# react draggable window off the screen in Full Screen mode

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set the position for a draggable window for full screen mode. Sometimes I dragged the window to left and making the window to full screen, now the fullscreen window is off the screen (i.e. half of the full window is out of box).

Code -
https://codesandbox.io/s/draggabledialog-material-demo-forked-2b60nf?file=/demo.js

[image]

dragging it to left or right; clicking on FULLSCREEN.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fullscreen mode you can disable drag and drop: I am not used to MUI but something like that will work, but I am sure there is a better way of doing that:

```
PaperComponent={isFullScreen ? '' :PaperComponent}
```